# Commerce 1: Different default order status based on product types

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, emails, order, status, products

I want to assign different default order status based on product types.  Is this possible?

What I need to achieve is to send different email notifications based on product types.  Can this be configured or do I need to add logic to and customize the email templates?

Answer (score 2):

> Edit: I'm sorry! I missed **Commerce 1** in the title! This answer only applies to Commerce 2.

Take a look at the [`defaultOrderStatus`](https://docs.craftcms.com/commerce/v2/events.html#the-defaultorderstatus-event) event!

The description is a bit misleading—it's actually used to do exactly what you've described: alter the "default" completed order status in situations where it might not be desirable.

From the docs:

```php
use craft\commerce\Plugin as Commerce;
use craft\commerce\events\DefaultOrderStatusEvent;
use craft\commerce\services\OrderStatuses;
use yii\base\Event;

Event::on(
    OrderStatuses::class,
    OrderStatuses::EVENT_DEFAULT_ORDER_STATUS,
    function (DefaultOrderStatusEvent $e) {
        $myOverriddenOrderStatus = Commerce::getInstance()->getOrderStatuses()->getOrderStatusByHandle('myCustomStatusHandle');

        $lineItems = $e->order->getLineItems();

        foreach ($lineItems as $lineItem) {
            // Your logic for checking the ProductType would
            // replace this basic test:
            if ($lineItem->price > 500) {
                $e->orderStatus = $myOverriddenOrderStatus;
            }
        }

        // Whatever `$e->orderStatus` ends up being by the time we exit
        // this event listener will be used as the new `OrderStatus`.
    });
```

Comment: That's too bad; is there a solution for Commerce 1?  Do I have to create a plugin for this?